# Can I install a Managed Package in a Pre Release Org?

Tags: managed-package, summer-13, pre-release

Fairly simple question, as the title asks: Can I install a Managed Package in a Pre Release Org?

I am getting a Package Not Found Error as shown in the image below.

If I try to install the Package in any other org it is successful.

[image: Package Not Found]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems link the managed package would need to be created in a pre-release org for it to install in a pre-release org.

From [Deploying and Testing Managed Package on Winter '10 Pre-Release?](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/AppExchange-Directory-Packaging/Deploying-and-Testing-Managed-Package-on-Winter-10-Pre-Release/td-p/148983)

> You can create a managed package from scratch on pre-release.  There is no way to take an existing managed package and deploy it onto pre-release.  If you have a sandbox organization that has already been upgraded to Winter '10, you can test your package in it.
>
> Andrew Smith
>   Director of Product Management, Force.com
>   salesforce.com

Comment: Old quote, but it still holds true. Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: The Winter '14 preview instructions for ISVs here (PartnerForce login required) https://org62.my.salesforce.com/apex/PP2ContentFramePage?l=/06830000003qGKW&p=PP_Content say that you should create two sandboxes, one with the managed package installed and one without it installed, then when the org gets upgrade to Winter '14 you can test app installation on the latter.  Can't see why they would mention 2nd sandbox in this case if you can't install managed package on a pre-release (unless that's different to sandbox preview org).